Vim search in normal command and newline / CR
I am trying to perform a search within a :norm command, and I am having some problems.
The following possibilities seem to work (in order to perform a search of 'abcd' from the beginning of the buffer):
:normal gg/abcd^M
:exe 'normal gg/abcd^M'

(where ^M is a literal newline character, inserted by typing Ctrl-VEnter).
However, trying to avoid the literal newline is giving problems. The following does not seem to work:
:exe 'normal gg/abcd\<Enter>'

Any solutions? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you very much.

<Enter> perhaps should be <CR>. But do you really want to use :normal? Why not use the command line once you pressed :? gg becomes :1, /abcd -> :call search('abcd'), overall it should be :1 | call search('abcd')<CR>

Thanks for your comment . I am experimenting with Vim macros and normal commands.


Do not overuse normals. If you are inside mapping then do simply gg/abcd<cr>; if you are inside script then prefer function calls, such as :h cursor(), :h search(), etc.

In VimScript ''-strings do not allow any substitutions inside. So they are different from ""-strings.

""-strings work as in C, that is "\r\<cr>\<enter>\<return>".

If you are both inside map-command and ""-string then both substitute rules apply, leftmost, i.e. map, first.



There is a way to do what you want without :norm:
:1 | /abcd

This will send you to the first appearance of "abcd". If you want to execute a command here (which could be a norm command) you can do this:
:1 | /abcd/[command]


Thanks. Interesting the possibility to add the command there.
